# Daemon listening on a port, make port accessible from network requests on Azure

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, port, port-forwarding, bindings

I have a software daemon listening on an arbitrary port, lets say 7500

I would like that server and port to be accessible from the outside world.

The daemon is on a virtual machine on Microsoft Azure, I already set inbound and outbound rules on the network resource group for that port, but this still seems only accessible on localhost.

Something about binding? Not sure anymore

Any insight appreciated

Comment: Start with `netstat -ban`, check if your process binds to `0.0.0.0` on port `7500`. If so, check the OS firewall and make sure you allow `7500/TCP` inbound for ALL profiles (Domain/Private/Public -- if it's Windows). If Linux, `sudo netstat -ltpe` and `sudo iptables -nL`.

Comment: Also if this is an ASM Virtual Machine (rather than ARM) make sure you have the right __Endpoint__ exposed (Portal -> VM -> Endpoints).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest performing a network capture on the server.

If the connection is blocked by the Azure side, you shouldn't get any packet on the server. In this case, please check the inbound rules of the NSG.

If the connection is blocked by the server itself, you will see the packet in the captured data. In this case, please check the firewall of the server.